# Difference between Java Expressions and Java Scriplets in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I find myself needing to learn a little bit of JSP for my Software Engineering class. One of our homework questions is as follows:

```
What are the output of these two code snippets if the parameter "myText" has the
value "JSP is fun"?

<% request.getParameter("myText"); %>

...and...

<%= request.getParameter("myText") %>
```

Here's my answer:

> The first line of code snippet should properly return "JSP is Fun".
>
> The second line of code should also properly return "JSP is Fun" as
>   it is an expression, which means it does not require a semi-colon
>   to function correctly (and would not work with one).

Am I missing something glaringly obvious, or is there really nothing more to this relatively simple question?

Comment: Are you really learning this nowadays? That's old course material then...

Comment: Expression doesn't require semi-colon, as they are passed as an argument to the method.

Comment: Even more, the semicolon is **disallowed**.

Comment: @BalusC -- Well, part of the class involves handling legacy code that's been developed by students every semester since 2001. So, "old" comes with the territory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one will not print anything since it's surrounded with a `<% ... %>` tag.

The second one will print `JSP is fun` since it's surrounded with a `<%= %>` tag.

The `=` part in the tag indicates that it should print out the return value of the code inside the tag.

On a side note, the first code snippet can also print out the value `JSP is fun` if it was written as such:

```
<% out.println(request.getParameter("myText")); %>
```

Comment: Indeed. See also this 10 year old official tutorial: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are used to print some value on the page, whereas scriptlets are statements. Your best bet is to go and check the generated class.